# N-body simulation with collisions

Tags: c++, vector, simulation

I wrote a brute-force 3-dimensional N-body simulation in C++ which works as expected.

I tried to implement **inelastic** particle collisions by including the line "myPhys.Collisions(particleList);" as part of my for-loop in the main.cpp where "Collisions" is defined in the "Physics" class (also shown below).

The code runs and produces output in data.csv. However, sometimes the run is interrupted by "Segmentation fault: 11" and the collisions lead to unexpected behavior.

I am wondering if I am somehow not handling vectors correctly in the "Collide" function, especially in the lines

```
// create particle with new parameters

Particle newParticle(newMass, newPosition, newVelocity);

// replace first particle in collision with new particle

particleList[idx1] = newParticle;

// erase second particle in collision

particleList.erase(particleList.begin()+idx2);
```

I should also mention that I'm new to C++ so I apologize if I'm doing something stupid.

The full code is available at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b3oq7x546c9lktv/AAAdUE7Nrzaiov0TaGtgjbfNa?dl=0

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "vectorops.h"
#include "particle.h"
#include "physics.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

ofstream myData;
myData.open("data.csv");

// initialize a vector of particles
int numParticles = 20;
vector<Particle> particleList;
for(int i = 0; i < numParticles; i++){
    particleList.push_back(Particle(1));
}

// declare physics engine
Physics myPhys;

// time evolution
for(int t = 0; t < 10000; t++){
    // calculate force on every particle
    vector< vector<double > > currentForces = myPhys.forceList(particleList);
    // iterate over particleList
    for(int i = 0; i < numParticles; i++){
        if(i < particleList.size())
        {
            // compute accelerations
            particleList[i].updateAcceleration(currentForces[i]);
            // increment velocities
            particleList[i].updateVelocity();
            // increment positions
            particleList[i].updatePosition();
            // print coordinates of each particle
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                myData << particleList[i].getPosition().at(j) << ",";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                myData << 0 << ",";
            }
        }
    }
    // update particleList after collisions
    myPhys.Collisions(particleList);
    myData << "\n";

}

myData.close();


return 0;
}
```

extract from Physics.cpp

```
void Physics::Collide(vector<Particle> &particleList, int idx1, int idx2){

// compute parameters of new particle

double m1 = particleList[idx1].getMass();
double m2 = particleList[idx2].getMass();
double newMass = m1+m2;

vector<double> newVelocity;
vector<double> v1 = particleList[idx1].getVelocity();
vector<double> v2 = particleList[idx2].getVelocity();
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    newVelocity.push_back((m1*v1[i]+m2*v2[i])/newMass);
}

vector<double> newPosition;
vector<double> x1 = particleList[idx1].getPosition();
vector<double> x2 = particleList[idx2].getPosition();
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    newPosition.push_back((m1*x1[i]+m2*x2[i])/newMass);
}

// create particle with new parameters

Particle newParticle(newMass, newPosition, newVelocity);

// replace first particle in collision with new particle

particleList[idx1] = newParticle;

// erase second particle in collision

particleList.erase(particleList.begin()+idx2);


}



void Physics::Collisions(vector<Particle> &particleList){
for(int i = 0; i < particleList.size();i++){
    for(int j=0; j < i; j++){
        double dist = Vectors.distance(particleList[i].getPosition(),particleList[j].getPosition());

        if(dist < 0.01){
            Collide(particleList,i,j);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to find some tutorial on debugging (either with a pure gdb, or with Visual Studio in case of Windows) and at least share where it segfaults: it usually means you have some invalidated pointers.

Comment: @hanno I can't see the relation obviously.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that after "particleList" is resized as a result of a collision, the positions of the particles in "myData" are not correctly aligned with the previous time step.

A quick workaround is to simply move one of the colliding particles to a large distance from the others, rather than deleting it from the vector

```
// create particle with new parameters

Particle newParticle(newMass, newPosition, newVelocity);

// replace first particle in collision with new particle

particleList[idx1] = newParticle;

// move second particle to large distance

vector<double> farAway;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    farAway.push_back(1000000);
}

particleList[idx2].setPosition(farAway);
```

This is not particularly elegant, however. I am thinking that a more elegant approach might be to store the position histories in the particle objects themselves.